# jquery php unexpected token in wordpress theme

Tags: php, jquery

unexpected token '<'

testing it on a blank html page works, moving it to a wordpress theme fails.

the getimg.php returns the array correctly

```
$('body').backfade([<?php include'../inc/getimg.php' echo '"'.implode('", "', $image_files).'"' ?>]);
```

Comment: I've found that you need a comma before echo... maybe that's the reason

Comment: Wow, a PHP include inside a javascript function, you don't see that very often. Wonder why !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inject data into JavaScript this way.  Use `json_encode()`.

```
var image_files = <?php echo json_encode($image_files) ?>; // Outputs ['file1', 'file2', etc.]
$('body').backfade(image_files);
```

Without it, you are missing the escaping needed to interpret your data correctly, and opening up yourself to potential security issues.